# Multiplier using op-amps not simulating properly in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, multiplier

[image: Two multipliers simulated in Ltspice]

I'm trying to create a square of two signals (3 and 4 V) using multipliers logic with only opamps in LTpsice, but the Vout is incredibly high (about -400 kV for 3 V) and not accurate. Any idea why this circuit isnt working?

[VCC and VEE pins have been added (not there in image) still not working]

Comment: I don't see any multiplier circuits in your picture. You haven't put Vcc on some of the op-amps either.

Comment: sorry in this image VCC isnt added to a few Opamps, but in my simulation they are. It still isnt working

Comment: my theory was if x was the input signal, first we would get Log x, then log x + log x = log x^2, then taking antilog we would get x^2

Comment: Your question is about your circuit. If you don't show the circuit you are using then making an answer is a waste of time it seems. We can't see the circuit you are using in your simulator; you need to show it because the one above IS NOT a multiplier.

Comment: It is a multiplier, I've just shorted the inputs to the summing amplifier to get x^2, the logic behind the two is the same (instead of x*y im doing x*x)

Comment: OK, then it should work but, you haven't informed the reader of that in your question and, you haven't explained why you show two channels of squaring and you haven't done a transient run and shown a waveform that might settle down after a few milliseconds to 9 volts (top squaring circuit). Clearly your bottom circuit has to clip the output.

Comment: I've mentioned the output I get is an incredibly low DC voltage (about -400kV)

Comment: Some Vcc and Vee pins are missing supply rails. Fix that first.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the top string of amplifiers, D3 (I used a 1N4148) has about 0.7 amperes flowing though it. That means the voltage across R9 will be \$0.7A \times 1k = 700V\$ which will be your output voltage if you have unlimited output voltage from the opamp (LTspice, you can use a universal opamp that has almost unlimited output voltage).

Hence, what you are seeing is correct for the input voltages you are applying.